# how to handle big integer data more than 8 byte or more than 20 digits in c++

Tags: c++

size of `integer` is 4,`long long int` is 8 byte and it can access about 19 digits data and for unsigned long long int size also 8 byte but handle larger value than long long int but this is less than 20 digits.Is there any way that can handle over 20 digits data.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int a;//any data type more than 8 byte can handle
    cin>>a;
    if(a>789456123789456123123)//want to take a higher thand this digits
    {
        cout<<"a is larger and big data"<<endl;
    }
}
```

I searched about it for a while but didn't find helpful contents.All     about is java `biginteger`.

Comment: [GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library)  may be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no built-in types larger than `unsigned long long` in C++.

You have 2 options:

- Use a library which supports "BigInts" (for example [gmp](http://gmplib.org/))
- Implement your own "BigInt" class

Answer (score 1):

you can use library to implement that. 
many libraries are availabe. such as:

[Gmplib](https://gmplib.org/)

[bigint](https://gist.github.com/bloopletech/338338)

For details, see

[Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries)